# Unable to create venv with a different Python verison

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm installed python 3.6 on my Ubuntu 17.04. Now, I'm trying to create virtual environment with command:

```
python3.6 -m venv env
```

but I'm getting the following message:

```
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

    apt-get install python3-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment.

Failing command: ['/home/makeev/test2/l/bin/python3.6', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']
```

`sudo apt install python3-venv` hasn't helped, I have this package installed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you specifically installed `python3.6` instead of Ubuntu's default python3 version, which is `python3.5`, you have to install `python3.6-venv` instead of `python3-venv` since that would resolve to `python3.5-venv`.

To do so, you can use `sudo apt install python3.6-venv`.

Answer (score 6):

We usually use `$ python3 -m venv myvenv` to create a new virtualenv (Here `myvenv` is the name of our virtualenv).

Similar to my case, if you have both `python3.5` as well as `python3.6` on your system, then you might get some errors.

**NOTE:** On some versions of Debian/Ubuntu you may receive the following error:

```
 The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensure pip is not available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv package using the following command.
      apt-get installpython3-venv  
 You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv package, recreate your virtual environment.
```

In this case, follow the instructions above and install the python3-venv package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-venv
```

**NOTE:** On some versions of Debian/Ubuntu initiating the virtual environment like this currently gives the following error:

```
Error Command: ['/home/wgetdj/WorkPlace/Programming/Python/myvenv/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']
```

To get around this, use the virtualenv command instead.

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
$ virtualenv --python=python3.6 myvenv
```

**NOTE:** If you get an error like

> E: Unable to locate package python3-venv

then instead run:

```
sudo apt install python3.6-venv
```

Comment: This is the related bug https://askubuntu.com/questions/958303/unable-to-create-virtual-environment-with-python-3-6