# Cannot start venv with python3

Tags: python, python3, virtualenv

When trying to start a virtual environment I get:

```
~$ python3 -m venv homeassistant
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

    apt-get install python3-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment.

Failing command: ['/home/gal/homeassistant/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']
```

But when I try to install python3-venv I get:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install python3-venv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-venv is already the newest version (3.6.7-1~18.04).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 38 not upgraded.
```

I should have several python versions installed but I remove them as alternatives:

```
~$ sudo update-alternatives --config python3
There is only one alternative in link group python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3): /~$ sudo update-alternatives --config python3
There is only one alternative in link group python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3): /usr/bin/python3.7
Nothing to configure.usr/bin/python3.7
Nothing to configure.
```

Python version is 3.7.5:

```
~$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.5
```

OS version is:

```
~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

I think that the problem is becuase of 'python3-venv is already the newest version (3.6.7-1~18.04).' while the version I use is 3.7 and not 3.6. But I don't know how to proceed.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Your analysis is correct: 3.6's venv won't work with 3.7. You can either look for a 3.7 version in either apt or pip, or you can change to Py3.6.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to create venv with a different Python verison](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958303/unable-to-create-venv-with-a-different-python-verison)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a venv for your version of python.

```
sudo apt-get install python3.7-venv
```